# Android External write permission issue in samsung s8 and s9

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-permissions

I have a downloader class in my app that handles downloading new apk from the server into user android devices, to update the app.
 the whole module works great and grants read-write permission and download and installs the apk with no issue. The only problem is with Galaxy s9 and Galaxy s8 with version 8.0.0, I’m experiencing permission denied exception for external storage. 
I have tested it with multiple device and SDKs , nexus, nexus 5x, zte, sony Xperia. But It looks like only effects Galaxy S8 and S9.

## Error

> No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/app-release.apk: Neither user 10390 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

## Update activity code

```
    void downloadOrCancel() {

        if (downloader != null && downloader.isDownloading()) {
             cancel();
         } else {
            download();
         }
        //  updateUi();
    }

    private void cancel() {
        if(downloader != null)
                  downloader.cancel();
    }

    private void download() {
        //   Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        downloader = Downloader.newInstance(this);
        downloader.download(URL_APK);
    }


    private void checkPErmissions(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    12);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    13);

        } else {
            downloadOrCancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 12:
            case 13: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // get locations
                    checkPErmissions();
                } else {
                    //Close it
                    finish();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

## Manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />
```

Comment: Just as a quick sidenote, you don't need READ permission if you already have WRITE, just WRITE is sufficient.

Comment: I was actually wondering that myself ,thanks .any idea about my issue with Samsung phones ?

Comment: Did you also declare the permissions in the Manifest?

Comment: yes I already did .

Comment: I am not sure, to be honest, it may have to do something with the path, the way you are getting it, from `Environment` or something like that. I don't think I know the answer, and it's quite difficult to replicate.

Comment: I'm using downloadManager.Request to download a apk file, in request i set my destination to   request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/app-release.apk");

Comment: I posted an answer because it's a bit long, if it will not work I'll delete it so that it doesn't create any confusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up some stuff on your code, but everything seems fine to me. I post this as an answer because it's too long for a comment.

The last thing I can suggest is because it happens only on Samsung S8 and S9, maybe it has something to do with the permission to install/download files from unknown sources. In your Samsung go to:

`Settings`-->`Locked Screen and Security`-->`Install unknown apps`

And try to turn it on for your application.

Comment: I already tried that ,also I'm getting exception at downloading point and not starting my install intent .

Comment: @user3132471 Then I don't know :) maybe try moving the permission right after your app launches in `onCreate`, to make sure that the permission is there before the download.

Comment: that was it , I request permission at my login page , and entered update Activity .thanks man for help .